# What reference can I cite for the proof that the sum of n exponential variables follows a gamma distribution?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution, references

There is a fairly common theorem, which states that:

The sum of $n$ independent variables following an exponential distribution $\mathrm{Exp}(\alpha)$ follow an gamma distribution $\mathrm{Gamma} (n, 1/\alpha)$  (also known as Erlang distribution).

I'm using this theorem in my thesis. I've been asked to cite the paper that introduces, or, if it's not possible, to at least cite a paper that explicitly mentions it.

Anyone knows of any such papers?

Comment: Sadly the only reference I can think of for this is for a related phenomena that probably won't pass muster.

Comment: Does it have to be a paper? This is a standard result found in *many* text books. I'd even suggest providing the proof yourself and placing it in an appendix.

Comment: See, for example, R. Durrett (2005), *[Probability: Theory and Examples](http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Theory-Examples/dp/0534424414)*, 3rd ed., Duxbury Press, page 30. The recent fourth edition is available [on his website](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html) and you can search for the corresponding page number there.

Comment: A book should do actually. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Just be careful about notation.  Some people write $\Gamma(n,\lambda)$ instead of $\Gamma(n, \frac{1}{\lambda})$ as you write it.  In either case, the expected value is $\frac{n}{\lambda}$.  And of course, the result is more general too:  The sum of independent $\Gamma(s_i, *)$ random variables is a $\Gamma(\sum_i s_i, *)$ random variable ($*$ can be $\lambda$ or $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ whichever you like).  See for example, Sheldon Ross's _A First Course in Probability,_ Chapter 6.

Comment: Why create an appendix (@cardinal) where a short sentence will work?  It suffices to point out that the [characteristic function of $\Gamma(n,\alpha)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) is $(1-\alpha i t)^{-k}$ which is the $k^\text{th}$ power of $(1-\alpha i t)^{-1}$, the cf of the Exponential($\alpha$) distribution.  This implicitly defines the notation, too (@Dilip).

Comment: @whuber: My (unstated) point regarding the appendix was intended to encourage the OP to explicitly write out the proof for him or herself as a learning exercise. Placing such a thing in an appendix would just serve to record it and signal to the committee that you took the extra effort to address their concern. I can think of at least three ways to prove the result off the top of my head (one being the approach you mention), each depending on a different level of sophistication regarding assumed results. :)

Comment: @cardinal Granted.  Your suggestions are helpful and wise.  My unstated point is that an actual proof should be considered more authoritative than any citation (although, unfortunately, that is not the case in many fields).

Comment: @whuber: it seems to me we are on the same page here. My original remark was meant to suggest doing *both* since providing the proof explicitly *would* be more authoritative. Based on the committee's request I am guessing that this is not a thesis in statistics. So, that was another motivation for the suggestion regarding the appendix; that is, a proof may not seem relevant or necessary within the body of the thesis.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I need to cite a particular (standard) distribution result, I just reference one of the Johnson, Kotz and Balakrishnan books. For your particular case, I would go for:

> Johnson, Kotz and Balakrishnan. *Continuous Univariate Distributions,
>   Vol. 1*, 1994 ([amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471584959))